# Account Object Geocode Fields Not Showing On Page Layout

Tags: page-layout, account, geolocation, standard-field

I am unable to get standard geocode fields like Account:Shipping Latitude and Account:Shipping Longitude on Page Layout.I want to display these fields on my Account details page but unable to it.
I have also checked field level security and profile access.Everything is correct.Please Help[image]

Answer (score 3):

It'd recommend you to get familiar with [Geolocation Custom Field Help Page](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_field_geolocate_overview.htm&type=5). Unfortunately you cannot expose this field on a layout.

However, it's still possible to show its value by using a text formula field. For instance, if you want to expose Shipping Geolocation, the formula will look like this:

```
TEXT(ShippingLatitude) & ", " & TEXT(ShippingLongitude)
```

Not it's present in the layout editor:

[image]

Have in mind that Shipping Latitude and Longitude are part of Shipping Address compound field and the naming convention differs here. In a help link provided above you'll get the knowledge of how to refer to custom Geolocation fields.

Also, have in mind that to make use of standard Geolocation fields, you need to activate their updating upon Address change in `Setup -> Data Integration Rules`.

Comment: Thanks for Suggestion..!! So this is **fact** that we cannot expose standard geolocation fields on layout.?

Comment: @UtkarshVerma - that's true, you cannot. I updated my answer however about enabling standard geolocation fields updating - it's not turned on by default.

Comment: I turned that on. Infact I am able to populate the Standard Shipping latitude and longitude on Account which I can see after quering. But sadly that field is not visible on Details page.

Comment: @UtkarshVerma this field is editable in general but only via API actions / Apex etc. as you noticed.